# Check if an item is array or not

Tags: javascript

I have a data in the form of JS literal notation here.

```
data = {
    "Project": [
        {
            "Title": "Project1",
            "StartDate": "01/01/2013", 
            "EndDate": "01/07/2013",
            "Status": 1
        },
        {
            "Title": "Project2",
            "StartDate": "01/05/2013",
            "EndDate": "01/15/2013",
            "Status": 2
        }
});


var propV;
function validate(data){
    for(var key in data){
        propV = data[key];
        if(typeof propV === 'array){
            //alert('array')
        }
        else if(type propV === 'date'){
            //alert('date')
        }
        else if(type propV === 'string'){
            //alert('string')
        }
        else if(type propV === 'object'){
            //alert('object')
        }
    }
}
```

For the above code, I was expecting it show alert of an array. However, it alerts for object. What's used in JavaScript to detect if the item is an array or not?

Similary, if I have a similar data as above, how would I detect if an item is date or not? For now, if I try to do that, I am getting dates also as `string`

Comment: How does it alert at all, if you don't have valid syntax and the alert statements are commented out?

Comment: typeof but you have formatting issues in your `data` variable above.

Comment: @scrappedcola `typeof`*

Comment: @scrappedcola : Typed the code with hand in the above textbox. Editted now

Comment: There's a syntax error in your code. You have an unmatched parentheses right after data.

Comment: And a missing [ at the end of your 'Projects' array

Comment: @user1240679 `"01/05/2013"` is not a `Date`, it is a string. To check if the string represents a date format, you'd want to use `isNaN(Date.parse(yourString));`

Answer (score 0):

```
if Object.prototype.toString.call(myObject) == "[object Array]" {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: So, using `typeof` is not fullproof that means or I am comparing with the wrong `'array'` string. If I change in my code `typeof propV` to `typeof [object Array]`, that wouldn't work, is it?

Comment: This method is one of the few reliable ways of capturing arrays, dates, and some other types.  But note that in your data, you have no dates.  You have an object, with a single property containing an array, whose two elements are objects, all of whose properties are strings.

Comment: And no, `typeof` is certainly not as helpful as one might like.

Comment: Here is a fiddle that shows this implemented: http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/fBwYG/ (along with the syntax fixes)

Comment: @ScottSauyet : For validating the JSON, how would I detect if the above string is a date or not? Creating instance and seeing if it does or matching with a regex or something like that?

Comment: You might be able to detect that it is a valid representation of a date.  But it is not a date.  It is a string, one that could conceivably also represent something other than a date.  Are you just looking to detect whether that string might reasonably be interpreted as a date?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are objects. To test if a particular object is an instance of the `Array` "class" (I use that term loosely), use the `instanceof` operator:

```
if (yourThing instanceof Array) {
    // it is an array
} else {
    // it is not an array
}
```

Comment: When it works, it works great.  This doesn't catch arrays that are inherited from another context (like an iframe) however.

Answer (score 0):

Newer browsers have an [**Array.isArray()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) method, and for older browsers you'd use the polyfill from MDN:

```
if(!Array.isArray) {
  Array.isArray = function (vArg) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(vArg) === "[object Array]";
  };
}
```

used like:

```
var isArray = Array.isArray(data.Project); // true or false
```

Comment: So, using typeof alone is not fullproof? Does that means or I am comparing with the wrong 'array' string? If I use object.Prototype.toString.call and change my code from === `propV` to  === `[object Array]`, that wouldn't work, is it

Comment: `typeof` alone will return object for arrays, as all arrays are objects first. However the built in `isArray()` is now supported in all major browsers (newest version), so you should use that if it's available.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, you could do:

```
$.isArray(myArray);
```